# missing methods in Android method profiling with am utility

Tags: java, android, debugging, testing, android-debug

I am using android shell tool *am* to do some method profiling. My point is that method profiling requires the process id of the application. So, the application must be started before application profiling so that it can acquire the process ID. But if i start profiling then I may miss some initial code execution. That means I can miss some method calls. Any workaround for that? My goal is to log all method calls since the application started.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of command line tools add:

```
 Debug.startMethodTracing();
```

in your code (see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Debug.html#startMethodTracing()).

If you want to profile the entire application adding this method to [Application.onCreate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#onCreate%28%29) is probably a good place to start.

If you don't have the source code you have to live with the other method (DDMS, am profile).
`am start` also has an option to start profiling

```
am start [-D] [-W] [-P <FILE>] [--start-profiler <FILE>]
               [--R COUNT] [-S] <INTENT>
```

so if you launch your Activity with `<INTENT>` it might be useful.

Comment: Hi how can I tell which method in my application is exercised first to add that profiling call? And also what if I want the profiling without source code?

Comment: yes i want to use ddms or am, but they require the process ID right? but to get that I need to launch the app first, so i may lose some initial method calls. How can i get that? Any idea?

Comment: am option to start profiling is, am profile <PROCESS_ID> start <TRACE_FILE>, so how can i get the process id without launching the application?  if I already launch the application and again launch it with intent will the initial codes be re-exercised? I mean first start the application, then launch profiler, then relaunch the application with intent?